# subtracting values between columns both ways

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find those values that are in column 1 and not in column 2 and vica versa. It can look like this: take fist row in the first column and look if there is same number in the second column if so then on the third column write 0 (substraction) and if there won't  be the same number then write searched number or error, doesn't  matter. This should work both ways (some numbers can be in col2 but not in col1, those i need to find aswell). So probably there would be 2 formulas in 2 columns. one searching from col1 to col2, and same for col2 to col1. And if there for example in col1 would be twice some value and in col2 just once, than it should show for the first number  0 and for second number error or searched number.

Dataset looks like this:

| Col1 | Col2. |
| --- | --- |
| 42646 |  |
| 55 | 42646 |
| 77 |  |
|  | 33 |
| 25 | 77 |

| Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 |  |
| 55 | 0 |
| 0 |  |
|  | 33(or error,NA etc) |
| 25 | 0 |

I have tried vlook up, but wasn't sucesfull.

Comment: So what was your VLOOKUP attempt and what did you expect from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shame you haven't added a sample in your data that would show what you meant with:

> "*And if there for example in col1 would be twice some value and in col2 just once, than it should show for the first number 0 and for second number error or searched number.*"

Your requirements make this a little tricky, but try:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=IF(A1="","",IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A1)-COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)<0,A1,0))
```

Formula in `D1`:

```
=IF(B1="","",IF(COUNTIF(A:A,B1)-COUNTIF(B$1:B1,B1)<0,B1,0))
```

Comment: You are right I should have add that option too. But I've tried you solution and it works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is what you are looking for. You can use for **Col3**:

```
=IF(A2:A6="", "",IF(ISNA(XMATCH(A2:A6,B2:B6)),A2:A6,0))
```

and for **Col4**:

```
=IF(B2:B6="", "", IF(ISNA(XMATCH(B2:B6,A2:A6)),B2:B6,0))
```

Both formulas returns `0` if the value was found (including blanks), otherwise the missing value.

You can put all together using `HSTACK`:

```
= HSTACK(IF(A2:A6="", "",IF(ISNA(XMATCH(A2:A6,B2:B6)),A2:A6,0)),
  IF(B2:B6="", "", IF(ISNA(XMATCH(B2:B6,A2:A6)),B2:B6,0)))
```

Or using `LET` to avoid repetitions.

```
= LET(A, A2:A6, B, B2:B6, HSTACK(IF(A="","",IF(ISNA(XMATCH(A,B)),A,0)),
   IF(B="", "", IF(ISNA(XMATCH(B,A)),B,0))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

You can use `XLOOKUP` too, but the formula is longer, because the first three input arguments are required:

```
=IF(ISNA(XLOOKUP(A2:A6,B2:B6, A2:A6)),A2:A6,0)
```

Comment: Thank You David, It works I just forgot to add in my sample option when in COL1 you have for example three times 400 and in col2 just two times, so in col3 it will show two times 0 and one time 400. But I have tried solution from Jvdv and it works, so it's fine:)